# View Flutter widget tests in simulator

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to see the UI tests in the simulator?

I am writing some tests for a widget which has animation and want to verify my tests are triggering the animation correctly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found the [answer](https://flutter.io/testing/#widget-testing) from the Docs page:

> To help debug widget tests, you can use the debugDumpApp() function to visualize the UI state of your test or simply flutter run test/widget_test.dart to see your test run in your preferred runtime environment such as a simulator or a device. During a flutter run session on a widget test, you can also interactively tap parts of the screen for the Flutter tool to print the suggested Finder.

Comment: Is it possible to run specific test from widget_test.dart file. I mean widget_test.dart has 3 tests and how to run only second of these in runtime environment (simulator)? flutter run test/widget_test.dart launches all of these in that file.

Answer (score 18):

run from command line

```
 flutter run -t test/your_test.dart
```

-t is for target file

if it tells you it couldnt find the apk you may have to tell it which flavor to use like this

```
flutter run --flavor uat -t test/your_test.dart
```

Comment: Tests worked well with the first command, but since we introduced Flavours I cannot run tests on device/simulator. It wants flavor and when I pass it, my app running instead of test.

Comment: @AntonDerevyanko You can actually create a flavor for testing and have it launch your test config with mock dependencies etc