# How to visualize rendered widget in test? Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I am writing some widget tests and very often I get overflow errors. I would love to be able to visualize the widgets pumped in a test to help me in debugging. Something similar to setting headless to false in web testing frameworks. Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [View Flutter widget tests in simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52023359/view-flutter-widget-tests-in-simulator)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Flutter Layout Explorer](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/inspector) ,

> The Flutter Layout Explorer helps you to better understand Flutter
> layouts. Currently, the Layout Explorer only supports exploration of
> flex layouts, but it may be extended to other types of layouts in the
> future.

You also have an option to use [Codepens](https://medium.com/flutter/announcing-codepen-support-for-flutter-bb346406fe50). It is great for visualizing ,sharing your UI design, you can also embed pens on your site/blog